# QRegularExpression match pattern

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I want to **QRegularExpressionMatch** returns true in the following cases:

- The string **starts** with FO . "*There is one space after FO*"
- The string **starts** with @FOOB.
- The string **contains** FOOBAR.

So, I did:

```
QRegularExpression rx("(^(\\bFO\\s\\b|\\@\\bFOOB\\b)) | (\\bFOOBAR\\b)");

QString string0 = "Anywhere FOOBAR in the string";
QString string1 = "FO in the beginning";
QString string2 = "@FOOB in the beginning";

QRegularExpressionMatch match = rx.match(string1);
if (match.hasMatch())
    QTextStream(stdout) << match.captured(0) << endl;
```

in the code above, there is three patterns. the first and second match in the beginning of the string for FO and @FOOB, the third pattern match anywhere in the string.
Without the third pattern, the code works fine for string1 and string2. With the third pattern, it works just for string0 and string2 and not for string1. I guess the space after FO not match the third pattern then the all the match fails? There is | operator between [first, second] and the third pattern!
Or I miss something, someone can help?
Thank you !

**Edit:**
Find solution 30 seconds after I posted: These extras space are the problem

```
QRegularExpression rx("(^(\\bFO\\s\\b|\\@\\bFOOB\\b)) | (\\bFOOBAR\\b)");  
                                                     ^ ^
```

But I'm not convinced ! Why we use parenthesis then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brief

As you've mentioned, you have spaces in your regex, which is why your regex is not working. This solution reduces the number of steps required to return a match.

### Code

The regex below can be used if you only want to ensure the string is valid. Note that if the `\s` is absolutely required (and a word boundary `\b` doesn't suffice after the `^FO` option, you can simply add it to the regular expressions below so that `FO` becomes `FO\s`

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Bb5E7V/2)

```
^(?:@FOOB|FO|.*\bFOOBAR)\b.*
```

If you are looking for valid strings and trying to return the match as well, you can use the following regex instead.

```
(?:^(?:@FOOB|FO)|\bFOOBAR)\b
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Anywhere FOOBAR in the string
FO in the beginning
@FOOB in the beginning
FOOBAR is in the string
In the string is FOOBAR
@FOOBAR is valid because foobar (uppercase) exists

Anywhere FOOBARY in the string
Anywhere FOOBA in the string
FOO is not a valid start
@FOOBA is not a valid start
The @FOOB is not at the start
```

#### Output

Below shows matches only

```
Anywhere FOOBAR in the string
FO in the beginning
@FOOB in the beginning
FOOBAR is in the string
In the string is FOOBAR
@FOOBAR is valid because foobar (uppercase) exists
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:@FOOB|FO|.*\bFOOBAR)` Non-capture group to match either of the following

  - `@FOOB` Match this literally
  - `FO` Match this literally
  - `.*\bFOOBAR` Match the following

    - `.*` Any character any number of times
    - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
    - `FOOBAR` Match this literally
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `.*` Match any character any number of times

Comment: Excellent !, can you edit explanation and add what does it mean ? and : in the beginning ?

Comment: @Phiber I've added it to my explanation. It's a non-capture group. Basically, instead of capturing whatever matches in the parentheses `()`, it doesn't. It's used to separate logic just as you would in an `if` statement. In this case it's used to say *match this, or this, or this* (but don't capture it)

Answer (score 1):

You can prune the regex a bit more after remiving unnecessary spaces:

```
QRegularExpression rx("^(?:FO\\s|@FOOB\\b)|\\bFOOBAR\\b");
```

Details:

- `^(?:FO\\s|@FOOB\\b)` - `FO` and any whitespace or a whole word `@FOOB` at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `\\bFOOBAR\\b` - a whole word `FOOBAR`